# Reduce class cover with factor $8$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all $[a,b)\times[c,d)$ with $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$. This set covers $\mathbb{R}^2$

We can induce the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the function $ \textbf{c}:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ given by $\textbf{c}[a,b)\times[c,d)=(b-a)(d-c)$ in the usual way. Lets call the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_2$

A reduce class cover $\mathcal{B}$ with factor $C$  is a subset of $\mathcal{A}$ that still covers $\mathbb{R}^2$ and such that for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$ there exists $B\in \mathcal{B} $ with $A\subset B$ and $\lambda^*_2(B)\leq C\, \lambda_2^*(A)$.

I want to prove that the sets of the form

$$\left[\displaystyle\frac{j-1}{2^n},\displaystyle\frac{j+1}{2^n}\right)\times\left[\displaystyle\frac{k-1}{2^m},\displaystyle\frac{k+1}{2^m}\right)$$

are a reduce class cover with factor $8$ for $\lambda^*_2$.

I got that this family is a reduce class cover with factor $16$  of $\lambda^*_2$. But I could not improve this result.

**I did the following:**

Choose $n,m$ such that $2^{-n-1}\leq b-a <2^{-n}$, $2^{-m-1}\leq d-c <2^{-m}$ and $k,j$ integers with $k-1\leq 2^n\, a <k$ and $j-1\leq 2^m \, c<j$ then we have that 
$$[a,b)\times[c,d)\subset \left[\displaystyle\frac{j-1}{2^n},\displaystyle\frac{j+1}{2^n}\right)\times\left[\displaystyle\frac{k-1}{2^m},\displaystyle\frac{k+1}{2^m}\right)$$
The length of the right hand set is $1/2^{m+n-2}$. Furthermore, since $1/2^{n+1}\leq b-a $ and $1/2^{m+1}\leq d-c $ we conclude that 
$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{m+n-2}}\leq 16(b-a)(d-c)$$
and this implies that I said.

Someone knows how to improve this bound?

Comment: What is $\lambda_2^*$? Do  you mean $\lambda_2$?

Comment: The outer measure of the Lebesgue measure

Comment: If $D_m=[0, 2^{-m})\times [0,4^{-m})\subset $ $B(j,k,n)= [(j-1)/2^n,(j+1)/2^n)\times [(k-1)/2^n, (k+1)/2^n)$ then $n\leq m+1,$ but then $\lambda ^*_2(B(j,k,n)/\lambda^*_2(D_m)=$ $2^{2 n}/2^{- 3 m}\geq 2^{2 m-1}$ so there is no finite factor $C.$

Comment: I don't know what you did but in that case $k=j=-1$ and $n=m-1$.

Comment: The idea is that $D_m$ is a rectangle whose side-lengths are $2^{-m}$ and  $4^{-m}$ but $B(j,k,n)$ is a square of side-length  at least $2^{-m}. $ So  $\lambda (B(j,k,n))\geq 2^m \lambda (D_m).$  And there is no upper bound $C$ for $2^m$ for all $m\in N$.  (I may have an arithmetic error in my previous comment)

Comment: The point is that you can find a square with at most 8 times the size of the rectangle. I found that you can do that but with 16 as a factor.

Comment: If the rectangle $D_m$ is a subset of a square then the area of the square is  at least $2^m$ times the area of $D_m$.

Comment: Now, I see your point. I'll edit the question to fix it.

Comment: Anyway I could not improve the bound.